Issue with Integration Re-arranging
I am looking at a system where I have the following integration $$
\bigg(\int dx \hspace{5pt}g^*(x)A^*(x+y)A(x)\bigg)\times\bigg(\int dx \hspace{5pt} g(x)A^*(x)A(x+y)\bigg)
$$
These are of course complex conjugates of each other, my main aim is to find a way to obtain $\langle|g(x)|^2\rangle$, so far I have tried the following:
$$
\int dx dx'(g^*(x)A^*(x+y)A(x))\hspace{5pt}(g(x')A^*(x')A(x'+y))
$$
in which as we know $x=x'$
$$
\int dx dx \hspace{2pt} |g(x)|^2|A^*(x+y)A(x)|^2
$$
which gives:
$$
\langle|g(x)|^2\rangle=\frac{\int dx  \hspace{2pt} |g(x)|^2|A^*(x+y)A(x)|^2}{\int dx|A^*(x'+y)A(x')|^2}
$$
whereas this can't be true if you follow from the top by saying the initial product of integrations gives you the average of $g^*(x)$ and $g(x)$. It would imply that $$
\langle|g(x)|^2\rangle=|\langle g(x)\rangle|^2
$$
Which cannot be true. So, if there a clearer way (if at all possible to write the first product expression to obtain a true average for $|g(x)|^2$.

There's no such thing as $\int dxdx$.
